# Php: can a user generate array in a post/get request?

Tags: php, arrays

I was dealing with security, and I came up with an idea:

```
if (!isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $_POST['id'] = 0;
}

$_POST['id'] = (int)$_POST['id']; // kill SQL injection
```

but what if `id` was an array? It would force this method to knee! But I dont know if its even possible to generate array.

Comment: What you mean by `id was an array?`

Comment: An array would be cast to `0` or `1`, depending on its truthiness. And why don't you just use SQL queries with bound parameters?

Comment: ok, but if its an object, it does fail. An (int) is always faster than bounding

Comment: You could iterate the values and cast each to integer

Comment: Why do you want to prevent SQL injection this way while much better alternatives are available?

Comment: please encrypt you id

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel: php has a nice set of filters to deal with $_GET and $_POST: see http://php.net/filter - there are filters even for arrays.

If in your form you have a `<SELECT multiple>`, which will send out an array of options picked by the user, the `name` must be something like `name="MySelection[]"` instead of a plain `name="MySelection"`. In this way, with the square brackets, an array will be automatically generated, and it will be `$_POST['MySelection'][0]`, `$_POST['MySelection'][1]` and so on. You can loop on it with a the usual `foreach`.